# Machthaber vs. Machtinhaber

Tags: etymology

Bei einer Recherche ist mir aufgefallen, dass der Begriff

> Machthaber

offenbar deutlich häufiger in der lebendigen Sprache Verwendung findet als

> Machtinhaber,

dabei erscheint mir letzterer präziser zu sein. Ein Inhaber kann eine Rolle oder eine Position innehaben und Macht scheint mir so eine Rolle zu definieren.

Was spricht also gegen den Machtinhaber?

Comment: Macht ist keine Rolle oder Position? Ein Machthaber "**hat die Macht**" (so zu regieren wie er will usw.).

Comment: Prinzipiell spricht nichts gegen "Machtinhaber". Nur eben dass man das so nicht sagt. Man sagt "Machthaber". - Es spricht auch nichts dagegen, "Molf" zu sagen, aber wir sagen halt "Tisch".

Comment: neutral <-> negativ: ein Machtinhaber ist berechtigt, einem Machthaber wird das Recht (durch die Gegenseite) abgesprochen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Inhaber* ist ein "Besitzer" oder "Eigentümer" - meistens von etwas Konkretem, Anfassbaren, im übertragenen Sinne einer konkreten Position.

- Führerscheininhaber
- Ladeninhaber
- Kontoinhaber
- Titelinhaber
- ...

Keiner dieser Begriffe sagt direkt, dass der Inhaber mit dem, was er besitzt auch tatsächlich etwas anstellt (Ein Führerscheininhaber muß nicht notwendigerweise Autofahrer sein, ein Kontoinhaber nicht notwendigerweise Geldgeschäfte tätigen).

Machthaber kann man nicht sein, ohne die Macht auch *auszuüben* (denn es ist die *Tätigkeit*, die *Nutzung* der Macht, die den Machthaber definiert, nicht der *Besitz* der Macht - was ich im Übrigen auch nicht als "Position oder Rolle" definieren würde) - Ein Machthaber ist also etwas leicht anderes als ein Machtinhaber.

Prinzipiell wirst du also praktisch immer den Begriff "Machthaber" verwenden wollen, das ist auch bei weitem gebräuchlicher.

Comment: Ein Machthaber wäre demnach ein Spezialfall eines Machtinhabers? P.S.: Das mit dem Ausüben ist ein interessanter Punkt!

Comment: @Lykanion Vielleicht eher andersrum - wenn denn *Machtinhaber* ein gebräuchlicher Begriff wäre: Ein Machtinhaber ist ein Machthaber, der seine Macht nicht notwendigerweise ausübt, vielleicht wäre König *Johann Ohneland* (John Lackland) so ein armes Würstchen....

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich meinte eigentlich, mein konkretes Beispiel wäre eins. Der wollte, aber konnte nicht.

Comment: Mir gefällt die Begründung über das Ausüben gut. Vielleicht nochmal zur Präzisierung eine Umschreibung meiner ursprünglichen Frage: Wenn ich heute einen Zeitungsartikel über die wackeligen Friedensverhandlungen von Ost- und West-Elbonien schreiben wollte, spreche ich vom "Machthaber Müller" oder vom "Machtinhaber Müller"? Das sehe ich jetzt als geklärt.

Answer (score 4):

Meinem Verständnis nach ist "Macht" an sich keine Rolle oder Position. Die Rolle wäre wohl eher die des "Mächtigen".
Man kann zwar eine Position innehaben, die einem dann Macht verleiht, aber das ist indirekt. Ein Machthaber verfügt dagegen direkt über Macht.

Der Ausdruck scheint mir auch eher für Diktatoren und Gewaltherrscher u.ä. gebräuchlich zu sein, also Menschen, die sich nicht so einfach aus ihrer Position abberufen lassen.

Der Duden kennt den Begriff jedenfalls nicht, und auch laut DWDS und Google ngram taucht er nur mit verschwindend geringer Häufigkeit auf, allerdings mit steigender Tendenz seit 1950.

[image: Machthaber,Machtinhaber:]
[image: Machtinhaber:]

Comment: Ich frage mich, wie viele dieser Einträge auf "Machthaber Gaddafi" zurückzuführen sind

Comment: Danke für die übersichtliche Hintergrundrecherche. So etwas ähnliches hatte ich im Vorfeld auch gemacht, aber nicht so schön dokumentiert. Die Frage beantwortet sie allerdings nur teilweise.